# Git can't pull changes from reset

Tags: git, git-reset

I have three git repositories set up on my local machine and remote server. I make changes to the source code on my local machine, push to a bare repo on the server, log in to the server, and pull from the bare repo to my website:

```
Local Machine                    SERVER    
+++++++++++++++++        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+  Source Code  +        +                      Website  +
+   repo 1 ---------------->bare repo----------->repo 3  +
+               + [push] +             [pull]            +
+++++++++++++++++        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I reset some commits on my local machine:

```
                   HEAD
  1     2     3     4
  o-----o-----o-----o

git reset --hard 1


HEAD
  1     2     3     4
  o-----o-----o-----o
```

Then I pushed the reset to the bare repo

```
git push -f
```

The problem is, I don't seem to be able to pull them from the bare repo to my website:

```
git pull origin master

From bare-repo
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

---

Edit: Output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate`

Local Machine:

```
* 0f8c9c7 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) commit 1
* 3e65e8f commit 0
* 821e81f commit -1
* 78c9427 commit -2
* 57ab3d3 commit -3
```

Server:

```
* 5075401 (HEAD, master) commit 4
* 39402d0 commit 3
* 4ebbf54 commit 2
* 0f8c9c7 commit 1
* 3e65e8f commit 0 
* 821e81f (origin/master, origin/HEAD) commit -1
* 78c9427 commit -2
```

Comment: What does `git log --graph --oneline --decorate` look like?  Feel encouraged to remove any details you don't want to share.

Comment: Guys, I thought that `git reset` only affects HEAD, and HEAD is just a symbolic reference that does not have SHA hash, so you cannot push or pull it, am I wrong? @Makoto

Comment: `git reset` moves HEAD to a specific point in your working tree.  It otherwise represents the tip of your tree.  Push and pull have no real context there.  In either event...I'd *really* like to see the output of that command I gave you...

Comment: @Makoto, sorry are you addressing me or the OP?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh:  I was addressing the OP.  For whatever reason I must've saw the "S" in your name and mistook it.

Comment: @Makoto on my local machine, the list ends at commit 1, and on the server, it lists commits 2, 3, and 4 as well. Both show HEAD pointing to the last commit

Comment: @symlink:  Add it to the question.

Comment: @Makoto see my edit

Comment: To be clear, you've got *two* separate machines that you're getting the output for the Git graph, right?  Can you do a `git fetch` too and then rerun the command?

Comment: @Makoto yeah, two different machines. I did a git fetch on the server, and (origin/master, origin/HEAD) moved up to commit 1

Comment: Here's what I'm saying.  `git log` will get the full history of your repository as your local machine knows it.  If you have two different outputs for `git log`, I'm assuming that you're running the command on two **separate** machines that both have the same repository.  If you've only run it on your local machine, then please only include the output from your local machine, otherwise it's very confusing.

Comment: @Makoto as per the ASCII image at the top of the question, I'm running the command on repo 1 and repo 3

Answer (score 1):

You have *three* repositories.  Each one has a `master` branch.

You did the `git reset` in repository #1, on your machine.  That set *your* `master` to the specified commit.

You then did `git push -f origin master:master` (or equivalent) from your machine, to repository #2 on the server.  That set repository #2's `master` to the specified commit.  That, in effect, *removed* the same commits in #2 as you removed with your `git reset` in your repository #1.

You then did `git pull` from repository #3 ("website").  This ran `git fetch` to see where `master` was in repository #2.  Repository #3 will then (in Git versions >= 1.8.4) set its own `origin/master` according to what it got from the Git for repository #2, and then run `git merge` to *add* any *new* commits it just got, to its (website's) `master`.

But repository #3 already had those commits on its master, *and more*.  So it does nothing, and says "I am up to date!  In fact, I'm even *more* up to date than you are, so there!"

Since you are trying to *remove* commits, you must get Git #3 working in repository #3 to remove *its* commits from *its* master.  Git is built around adding commits, not removing them.  You must use `git reset` there to remove them, or force-update Git #3's `master` to Git #2's `master`, or something along those lines.